# Send object id from success function to another function in parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a problem on parse.com in which i to take the id of an type and pass it to another function which uploads an image. Then take the type.id among with the image and post it to another function which saves the data to a class.

This is what i've tried until now without success.

--**OnClick code**

```
$('#submitId').on("click", function(e, f) {
         e.preventDefault();
        typeSave(typeid1);

        //var objnew1 = typeSave();

        console.log("inside onclick " + type2);
        var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
        var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
        var name = file.name; //This does *NOT* need to be a unique name
        var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
        parseFile.save().then(
            function() {
                //typeSave();
                type2 = typeid1;
                saveJobApp(parseFile, type2);
                console.log("inside save onclick " + type2);
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        );
    });
```

--  **Type Code**

```
var type;
var typeid1;
var type2;
    function typeSave() {
        var type = new Parse.Object("type");
        var user = new Parse.Object("magazia");
        //var bID = objbID;
       //user.id = bID;

        var cafebar = document.getElementById('cafe_bar').checked;
        if (cafebar) {
            var valueCafebar = true;
        } else {
            var valueCafebar = false;
        }
        var club = document.getElementById('club').checked;
        if (club) {
            var valueClub = true;
        } else {
            var valueClub = false;
        }
        var restaurant = document.getElementById('restaurant').checked;
        if (restaurant) {
            var valueRestaurant = true;
        } else {
            var valueRestaurant = false;
        }
        var pistes = document.getElementById('pistes').checked;
        if (pistes) {
            var valuePistes = true;
        } else {
            var valuePistes = false;
        }
        type.set("cafebar", valueCafebar);
        type.set("club", valueClub);
        type.set("restaurant", valueRestaurant);
        type.set("pistes", valuePistes);
        type.save(null, {
            success: function(type) {
            //saveJobApp(type.id);
            var typeid1 = type.id;
            console.log("inside type save " + typeid1);
              //return ;

            },
            error: function(type, error) {
                alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
            }
        });
    }
```

-- **Send Data to parse.com class code**

```
 function saveJobApp(objParseFile, type2) {
        var jobApplication = new Parse.Object("magazia");
        var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var description = document.getElementById('description').value;
        var website = document.getElementById('website').value;
        var phone = document.getElementById('phone').value;
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        var latlon = document.getElementById('latlon').value;
        var area = document.getElementById('area').value;
        var value = latlon;
        value = value.replace(/[\(\)]/g, '').split(', ');
        console.log("inside saveJobApp " + type2);
        var x = parseFloat(value[0]);
        var y = parseFloat(value[1]);
        var point = new Parse.GeoPoint(x, y);
        jobApplication.set("image", objParseFile);
        jobApplication.set("email", email);
        jobApplication.set("phone", phone);
        jobApplication.set("address", address);
        jobApplication.set("name", name);
        jobApplication.set("website", website);
        jobApplication.set("description", description);
        jobApplication.set("area", area);
        jobApplication.set("latlon", point);
        jobApplication.set("typeID", type2);
        jobApplication.save(null, {
            success: function(gameScore) {
               // typeSave(jobApplication.id);
            },
            error: function(gameScore, error) {
                alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
            }
        });
    }
```

So resuming i am trying when i click the button to first run the `typesave()` function, after when it posts the type on the type class in parse, to take to type.id from the success function and send it to the  `parseFile.save().then`
and then to send the `objectFile` and the `type2` (which is the `type.id`) it in `saveJobApp` and them to save it in class `magazia`

What i get from the console.logs is this

[image]
Which means that my code post to the type class and takes the type.id
but it doesnt send it to the `magazia` class via the parsefile save.
Any idea of what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed your mistake is not about the functions but about trying to pass the type.id as a string and not as a function in the saveJobApp function.

if you try making it like this

```
function saveJobApp(objParseFile , objtype) {
        var jobApplication = new Parse.Object("magazia");
        var type = new Parse.Object("type");

        type.id = objtype;
        jobApplication.set("typeID", type);
```

I think it will work.

And also update the onclick and the ParseFile save code to this

```
$('#submitId').on("click", function(e) {
    typeSave();
    });
    function PhotoUpload(objtype){

        var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
        var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
        var name = file.name; //This does *NOT* need to be a unique name
        var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

        parseFile.save().then(
            function() {
                saveJobApp(parseFile, objtype);
            },
            function(error) {
                alert("error");
            }
        );
    }
```

And the success function in typeSave()
should be something like this

```
type.save(null, {
            success: function(type) {
                PhotoUpload(type.id);
            },
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: actually you are right i had to pass it like an object i checked out your code and you where right!